# Windows PowerShell doesn't console.log the Date object from Node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell, date

I am trying to console.log Date object in Windows PowerShell by executing Node.js:

`node -e "var d = new Date();console.log('new date = ', d);"`

However, the PowerShell doesn't give me any date. The only thing I am getting is:

`new date=`

All other type of data get printed out, including time.

The only way I found to see the date in PowerShell is to add `.toString()` to my code:

`node -e "var d = new Date();console.log('new date = ', d.toString());"`

Then I get: 
[image: dateAsStringImage]

I don't have this problem in a simple CMD on the same system (Windows10Pro).
The above code (`node -e "var d = new Date();console.log('new date = ', d);"`) gets printed:

`new date= 2020-03-14T22:46:49.847Z`

If anyone has any idea how to solve this, I will appreciate a lot your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is merely a *display* problem:

The date string *does* print, but effectively *invisibly*, because the foreground (text) color chosen is apparently the same as PowerShell's *background* color.

A simple workaround is to pipe to `Write-Output`, which seems like a no-op, but actually causes `node` to suppress the coloring, so that the text prints normally:

```
PS> node -e "var d = new Date();console.log('new date = ', d);" | Write-Output
new date =  2020-03-15T03:07:06.798Z
```

Similarly,

- redirecting the output to a *file* would capture the text as expected (without the VT (Virtual Terminal) sequences that produce the colors in the console).
- copying and pasting the output line reveals the complete text.
- changing the console's background color to something like light green makes the date string directly visible in the output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It was the background color of PowerShell. The best way was to change the background color to black, now everything is visible incuding dates :)

Comment: My pleasure, @KaroDev, and good to know that black is a good background-color choice.